# Multi-devices support in Android

Tags: android, appium

I am trying to run a script on Multiple devices in Andriod platform, but I am unable to run. I went through Github page for a solution and found the following link about [Support multiple (Android) devices from a single Appium server](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/462)

But, still I can't figure out setup environment for multiple devices.

Comment: And what have you tried? Show us your current progress, so we can possibly help you.

Comment: Start the two appium servers parallel in the GUI, but its not running.
I don't have any idea about how to run in terminal. Please help me how to run single project scripts in multiple devices.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will help you.

//Running multiple emulators from single appium server

```
public class Test{

    WebDriver driver = null;
    int timeOut=180;
    int port=-1;

    Test(int port){
        this.port=port;
    }

    public void testEmulator(int p) throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.3");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Windows");

        capabilities.setCapability("udid","emulator-"+p);

        capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "your.app.pkg");
        capabilities.setCapability("app-activity",
            "your.app.pkg.Activity");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:"+this.port+"/wd/hub"),
        capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(50000);
    }

    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null)
            driver.quit();
    }

    public void runTest() {
        try {
            testEmulator(5554);     // for emulator on port 5554
            tearDown();
            testEmulator(5556);     // for emulator on port 5556
            tearDown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test(4723).runTest();       // appium server port 4723
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For sequential or parallel execution on multiple android devices, we need to -

1. Have separate Appium instance for each device or emulator
2. For each device/Appium instance, **provide different values for Appium port, Bootstrap Port, Device ID (ie UDID, not Device Name)**
3. Provide different Chrome Driver port, if using Chrome browser on the app

Check the below post, which uses Java Thread and Runnable interface for parallel execution - 
http://automationtestinghub.com/appium-parallel-execution/

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the GUI, I guess your environment is Windows? Then you can use the following batch:

```
@ECHO OFF

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium"

node server.js --app "<path-to-your-project>\bin\<app-name>.apk" -p <port-to-listen-on> -dp <device-port-to-connect-to-device-on>
```

With this you should be able to start two different Appium servers and using them parallel.

For a full list of all available commands, type `node server.js --help`.

If you installed Appium via npm, the path to server.js would be something like "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium" instead.

Comment: With Appium 1.4.0 the `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium"` path does not contain a server.js any more.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple android devices start your appium server with parameters:

- node appium.js -p 4476 -U `<device1_serial>`
- node appium.js -p 4475 -U `<device2_serial>`

You can select any port, but make sure they are different
 in your code, where you are creating driver, provide server url:

```
server1_url = "http://127.0.0.1:4475/wd/hub"
server2_url = "http://127.0.0.1:4476/wd/hub"
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

To run appium script on multiple devices

1. You have to start appium servers as per number of devices with
   different ports number.
2. Create driver instance with each port in
   your favorite language (java, ruby)
3. Run those script simultaneously.
4. You can also create thread based program which will create different
   driver instances.

Here I have create simple java thread based program

https://github.com/sameer49/Appium-Grid-For-Android

Answer (score 0):

I just use `uidi` instead of `uuid` then I can connect to multi-devices with only one Appium server.