# How can I run two parallel Appium instances?

Tags: appium

I am new to Appium.  I have covered major functionalities like swipe, scroll, zoom and others.

What is the procedure to run Appium in parallel for 2 real android devices simultaneously?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-devices support in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719755/multi-devices-support-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can start appium on different ports: `appium -p XXXX` 
Default appium is started on 4723.